# XSL:KEY Function for external file

Tags: xslt-2.0

I have an issue in key function, key function not running in following code.

my input is

**XML (Keys.xml)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Keys>
    <Key year="2001" name="ABC"/>
    <Key year="2002" name="BCA"/>
</Keys>
```

**XML to convert**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
    <text> .. .. <key>ABC</key> ...</text>
    <text> .. .. <key>BCA</key> ...</text>
</p>
```

**XSLT**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:key name="keydata" match="*[name() = document('keys.xml')]/Keys/Key" use="@name"/>
    <xsl:template match="key">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="key('keydata', .)/@year"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output**

```
<p>
    <text> .. .. <key ref="">ABC</key> ...</text>
    <text> .. .. <key ref="">BCA</key> ...</text>
</p>
```

**Desired Ouput**

```
<p>
    <text> .. .. <key ref="2001">ABC</key> ...</text>
    <text> .. .. <key ref="2002">BCA</key> ...</text>
</p>
```

Comment: Such a predicate `[name() = document('keys.xml')]` doesn't seem correct. Do you have an error message?

Comment: no, there is no error message

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    version="2.0">

    <xsl:variable name="keys" select="document('keys.xml')" as="document-node()"/>

    <xsl:key name="keydata" match="Key" use="@name"/>

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="key">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:attribute name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="$keys/key('keydata', current())/@year"/></xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:value-of select="."/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

In the XSL specification, there's an example entitled "[Example: Using Keys to Reference other Documents](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt20/#d5e22881)" that exactly matches your use case.

This is the resulting document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<p>
    <text> .. .. <key ref="2001">ABC</key> ...</text>
    <text> .. .. <key ref="2002">BCA</key> ...</text>
</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change `<xsl:key name="keydata" match="*[name() = document('keys.xml')]/Keys/Key" use="@name"/>` to `<xsl:key name="keydata" match="Keys/Key" use="@name"/>` and then `<xsl:attribute name="ref"><xsl:value-of select="key('keydata', .)/@year"/></xsl:attribute>` to `<xsl:attribute name="ref" select="key('keydata', . doc('Keys.xml'))/@year"/></xsl:attribute>`.